# How can effects from fixed-effects model in plm be plotted in R?

Tags: predict, effect, plm

I cannot get a plot for the effects I get from a fixed-effects model in `plm`. I tried using `effect()`, `predict()` and all kinds of packages like `sjPlot`, etc.
Is there a way of plotting it, especially also with interactions?

I always get error messages like:

```
Error in mod.matrix %*% scoef : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: For models produced by `plm::plm()`, there is a `predict` method available since `plm` version 2.6-2. See also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426168/4640346

Answer (score 0):

Try `fixef`? For instance, see below:

```
plm_2 <- plm(wealth ~  Volatility, data = ds_panel,index=c("rho"), model = "within")
y1 <- fixef(plm_2)
x1 <- as.numeric(names(y1))
plot(y1~x1, pch = 20, ylab = "FE", xlab = expression(rho))
```